# How to let a user to create a function? [ library ? ]

Tags: c, cuda

Is there any free library to let a user  easily build a C mathematical expression, which can be used like any other function? I mean c expression/function which could be as quick as 'inline' mathematical expression and could be used many times in program.
I think I can be done in C somehow, but does anybody can tell if it could be real if it have to be a CUDA dveice function?

Comment: How would the user call this function?

Comment: Do you mean something like [Automatic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_programming)?

Comment: Do you want a mathematical parser?

Comment: There are a fair number of mathematical evaluators, if that's what you mean.

Comment: It sounds like the OP wants (roughly) a mathematical JIT compiler. Which, I gotta say, would be pretty nice.

Comment: I am not sure what I want :). It seems to me, that a parsers/f mathematical evaluators have to parse an expression every time it need to be used. JIT/Automatic Programming needs to compile (whole?) scr code while I want to use CUDA (C on a GPU) , and there would be problem with compiling cuda device function.

Comment: libjit (which I discussed) seems to be able to create individual "functions" based on whatever series of instructions you want to call. How close is (at least the user-end code in) my answer to what you're looking for?

Comment: I don't think there is something like this for CUDA, as CUDA kernels are launched in parallel. I suppose you must do this part at the host and develop a way to execute an appropiate kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options. I assume you want something that the user can "call" several times, like this:

```
void *s = make_func("2 * x + 7");
...
printf("%lf\n", call_func(s, 3.0)); // prints 13
...
printf("%lf\n", call_func(s, 5.0)); // prints 17
...
free_func(s);
```

One option is to implement this as a recursive structure holding function pointers and constants. Something like:

```
enum item_type { VAR, CONST, FUNC };

struct var {
  enum item_type;
  int id;
};

struct constant {
  enum item_type;
  double value;
};

struct func {
  enum item_type;
  double (*func)(double, double);
  enum item_type *a, *b;
};
```

Then `make_func` would parse the above string into something like:

```
(struct func *){ FUNC, &plus,
  (struct func *){ FUNC, &times,
    (struct constant *){ CONST, 2 },
    (struct var *){ VAR, 'x' } }
  (struct constant *){ CONST, 7 } }
```

If you can understand that - the `enum type_item` in the `struct func` is used to point to the next node in the tree (or rather, the first element of that node, which is the `enum`), and the `enum` is what our code uses to find out what the item type is. Then, when we use the `call(void *, ...)` function, it counts how many variables there are - this is how many extra arguments the `call` function should have been passed - then replaces the variables with the values we've called it with, then does the calculations.

The other option (which will probably be considerably faster and easier to extend) is to use something like [libjit](http://www.gnu.org/software/dotgnu/libjit-doc/libjit.html) to do most of that work for you. I've never used it, but a JIT compiler gives you some basic building blocks (like add, multiply, etc. "instructions") that you can string together as you need them, and it compiles them down to actual assembly code (so no going through a constructed syntax tree calling function pointers like we had to before) so that when you call it it's as fast and dynamic as possible.

I don't know libjit's API, but it looks easily capable of doing what you seem to need. The `make_func` and `free_func` could all be pretty much the same as they are above (you might have to alter your calls to `call_func`) and would basically construct, use, and destroy a JIT object based on how it parses the user's string. The same as above, really, but you wouldn't need to define the syntax tree, data types, etc. yourself.

Hope that is somewhat helpful.

Comment: I guess I ought to change "constant"s to "literal"s. Oh well. I'll do it when I try actually implementing these for fun later tonight.

Comment: Your idea of fun and mine seem to differ greatly. :-D

Answer (score 2):

`libtcc` (from [TCC](http://bellard.org/tcc/)) can be used as a very small and fast JIT; see [`libtcc_test.cc`](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch/p?#euRx9UyUvHY/tests/libtcc_test.c) for sample usage.